# Using TFS2018 api to retrieve solution

Tags: c#, tfs

Using the TFS2018 api is it possible to retrieve all solution files related to a specific build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use [Get a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-a-build) api to get the **sourceVersion** of this build:

```
GET http://TFS2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=2.0
```

Then, you have two choices to retrieve all files that the build use:

1. Use [tf get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command) command.
2. Use REST API to download a zip folder for the sources. The api is as below:

~

```
GET http://TFS2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_api/_versioncontrol/itemContentZipped?path={FolderPath}&version={sourceVersion}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you may try (for git):

- Set "Tag sources on success" for build definition.
  [image]
- Get sources with tag through tfs rest api: [Get a specific version](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/items#get-a-specific-version)